# When radio button is checked - show select tag section

Tags: javascript, wordpress, radio-button, contact-form-7

So I'm using the plugin Contact Form 7 for WordPress, and I have this form with 2 radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="investorlandlord" value="I'm an Investor">
<input type="radio" name="investorlandlord" value="I'm a Landlord" tabindex="1">
```

When the I'm an investor button is checked I need the following  dropdown to appear under it:

```
<select name="finance" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" id="finance"><option value="Finance Available">Finance Available</option>...</select>
```

and when the other button is checked the I need this dropdown to appear:

```
<select name="properties" class="wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-select" id="properties"><option value="Number of Properties">Number of Properties</option>...</select>
```

Is there any easy way to do this in WordPress?

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/better-wordpress-showhide-elements/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem using this right here and it works perfect :)

```
jQuery(function(){
               jQuery("input[name=investorlandlord]").change(function(){          


            if ($(this).val() == "I'm a Landlord") {
            jQuery("#properties").slideDown()
            }
            else {
            jQuery("#properties").slideUp();
            }                                                            
       });
    });
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery("input[name=investorlandlord]").change(function(){          


            if ($(this).val() == "I'm an Investor") {
            jQuery("#finance").slideDown()
            }
            else {
            jQuery("#finance").slideUp();
            }                                                            
});
});
```